# Laravel syntax GroupBy for get column to array

Tags: laravel

i have database structure like this

Consumption Table

```
| ID | VOLTAGE | POWER | ENERGY |     CREATED_AT      |
| -- | ------- | ----- | ------ | ------------------- |
|  1 |     220 |  0.04 |      4 | 2023-05-03 13:04:05 |
|  2 |     210 |  0.03 |      5 | 2023-05-03 15:04:05 |
|  3 |     213 |  0.04 |      2 | 2023-05-06 02:04:05 |
|  4 |     221 |  0.05 |      4 | 2023-05-06 05:04:05 |
```

i have query like this

```
return Consumption::select(
      DB::raw('
        DATE(created_at) as date, //GroupBy DATE
        avg(voltage) voltage, //Average column VOLTAGE
        avg(power) power, //Average column POWER
        ? (energy) energy //how to get all data energy in array ?
     ')
  )
  ->groupBy('date')
  ->get();
```

**How to get all data energy in array ?**

My Expected:

```
[
  {
    "date": "2023-05-03",
    "voltage": "215",
    "power": "0.035",
    "energy": [4,5]
  },
  {
    "date": "2023-05-06",
    "voltage": "217",
    "power": "0.045",
    "energy": [2,4]
  }
]
```

Comment: Add only one tag relative to the database you're actually using.

Comment: @lemon, and why a <sql> tag? I see no SQL above. Is an SQL answer expected?

Comment: Okay thanks, but DB::raw mean SQL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In MySQL, you can make use of [`GROUP_CONCAT`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/aggregate-functions.html#function_group-concat)

```
SELECT 
    DATE(`created_at`),
    AVG(voltage),
    AVG(power),
    GROUP_CONCAT(energy)
FROM consumption
GROUP BY DATE(`created_at`)
```

Comment: There's also [JSON_ARRAYAGG](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/aggregate-functions.html#function_json-arrayagg) in case the data already contains `,` in it